# How to get all OIDs from a table?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, arccatalog

I have table which I need to get all the OID's from it.

I tried this code :

```
List<int> OIDList = new List<int>();
IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
queryFilter.SubFields = "OBJECTID";

for (int i = 1; i <= table.RowCount(queryFilter); i++) {
    OIDList.Add(i);
}
```

But the problem is there is some values were skipped, e.g. the table contains 60 row but the `OID` for the last row is 100.

In the code above, I can not catch any `OID` more than 60.

How can I get all the OIDs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the `ITable` interface if it is a standalone table.

```
List<int> OIDList = new List<int>();
ICursor pCursor = pTable.Search(null,False);

while((pRow = pCursor.NextRow) != null))
{
    OIDList.Add(pRow.OID);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot, i make some changes on the code now it's work properly.

```
List<int> OIDList = new List<int>();
IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
    queryFilter.SubFields = "OBJECTID";
    ICursor pCursor = pTable.Search(queryFilter, false);
    IRow pRow = null;
    while((pRow = pCursor.NextRow) != null))
    {
        OIDList.Add(pRow.OID);
    }
```